# How do shared pointers work?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

How do shared pointers know how many pointers point to that object? (shared_ptr, in this case)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Basically, `shared_ptr` has two pointers:  a pointer to the shared object and a pointer to a struct containing two reference counts:  one for "strong references," or references that have ownership, and one for "weak references," or references that don't have ownership.

When you copy a `shared_ptr`, the copy constructor increments the strong reference count.  When you destroy a `shared_ptr`, the destructor decrements the strong reference count and tests whether the reference count is zero; if it is, the destructor deletes the shared object because no `shared_ptr`s point to it anymore.

The weak reference count is used to support `weak_ptr`; basically, any time a `weak_ptr` is created from the `shared_ptr`, the weak reference count is incremented, and any time one is destroyed the weak reference count is decremented.  As long as either the strong reference count or the weak reference count is greater than zero, the reference count struct will not be destroyed.

Effectively, as long as the strong reference count is greater than zero, the shared object will not be deleted.  As long as the strong reference count or the weak reference count is not zero, the reference count struct will not be deleted.

Comment: s/As long as the weak reference count is greater/As long as either reference count is greater/ , of course.

Comment: great answer...  I'm familiar with how smart pointers work in general but i never knew the specifics of shared_ptr

Comment: And the great idea of `make_shared` is to bundle the two items (count struct and object) into a single chunk of memory so that you only one memory allocation (thus faster) instead of two... (okay, there is one other but nevermind). Also, it could be great to precise that the very idea of the separate count struct is for making it possible for a `weak_ptr` to know whether or not the object was deleted via the `expired` function > when the pointer of the count struct is null, there is no longer an object pointed to.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sorry for asking a question a bit late. If count struct and object are obtained in a single allocation, doesn't that make it difficult to free the object (when the use count goes to 0) while keeping the count struct alive (if there are still weak pointers)? I think most memory allocators don't allow freeing only part of the chunk they gave out as one piece. And if the whole memory must remain marked "in use" until the last weak pointer disappears, that makes weak pointers behave a lot like strong pointers.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: When using a single memory allocation for both count and object, the strong count determine when to call the destructor while both counts determine when to free the memory block. The "extra" retention of memory rarely is an issue in practice, since `weak_ptr` are not used that often to start with. If it is an issue for a specific case, then indeed you may wish to use separate allocations for it.

Comment: @MSalters No. How would they be "weak references" if they keep the object from being destructed.

Comment: @doug65536, the sentence MSalters corrected refers to the lifetime of the reference count struct, not the target object.

Answer (score 21):

I generally agree with James McNellis's answer. However there's one more point that should be mentioned.

As you may know, `shared_ptr<T>` may also be used when the type `T` is not fully defined.

That is:

```
class AbraCadabra;

boost::shared_ptr<AbraCadabra> myPtr;
// ...
```

This will compile & work. Unlike many other implementations of smart pointers, which actually demand the encapsulated type to be fully defined in order to use them. This is related to the fact that the smart pointer is supposed to know to delete the encapsulated object when it's no more referenced, and in order to delete an object one **must** know what it is.

This is achieved by the following trick: `shared_ptr` actually consists of the following:

1. An opaque pointer to the object
2. Shared reference counters (what James McNellis described)
3. A pointer to the allocated **factory** that knows how to destroy your object.

The above factory is a helper object with a single virtual function, which is supposed to delete your object in a correct way.

This factory is actually created when you **assign** a value to your shared pointer.

That is, the following code

```
AbraCadabra* pObj = /* get it from somewhere */;
myPtr.reset(pObj);
```

This is where this factory is allocated.
Note: the `reset` function is actually a **template** function. It actually creates the factory for the specified type (type of the object passed as a parameter).
This is where your type should be fully defined. That is, if it's still not defined - you'll get a compilation error.

Note also: if you actually create an object of a derived type (derived from `AbraCadabra`), and assign it to the `shared_ptr` - it will be deleted in a correct way even if your destructor is not virtual.
The `shared_ptr` will always delete the object according to the type that is sees in `reset` function.

So that shared_ptr is a pretty sophisticated variant of a smart pointer. It gives an awesome **flexibility**. However you should know that this flexibility comes at a **price** of an extremely bad performance compared to other possible implementations of the smart pointer.

On the other hand - there're so-called "intrusive" smart pointers. They don't have all that flexibility, however in contrast they give the best performance.

Pros of `shared_ptr` compared to inrusive smart pointers:

- Very flexible usage. Only have to define the encapsulated type when assigning it to the `shared_ptr`. This is very valuable for big projects, reduces dependencies greatly.
- The encapsulated type doesn't have to have a virtual destructor, still polymorphic types will be deleted correctly.
- Can be used with weak pointers.

Cons of `shared_ptr` compared to inrusive smart pointers:

1. Very barbaric performance and waste of heap memory. On assignment allocates 2 more objects: reference counters, plus the factory (waste of memory, slow). This however happens only on `reset`. When one `shared_ptr` is assigned to another one - nothing more is allocated.
2. The above may throw an exception. (out-of-memory condition). In contrast intrsusive smart pointers may never throw (apart from process exceptions related to invalid memory access, stack overflow and etc.)
3. Deletion of your object is also slow: need to deallocate another two structs.
4. When working with intrusive smart pointers you may freely mix smart pointers with raw ones. This is ok because the actual reference counting resides inside the object itself, which is single.
   In contrast - with `shared_ptr` you may **not** mix with raw pointers.

```
    AbraCadabra* pObj = /* get it from somewhere */;
    myPtr.reset(pObj);
    // ...
    pObj = myPtr.get();
    boost::shared_ptr<AbraCadabra> myPtr2(pObj); // oops
```

The above will crash.

Comment: You mention weak_ptr as an advantage of shared_ptr design. Is it not possible to have have weak_ptr with intrusive ptr? Or it would involve reinventing shared_ptr along with intrusive ptr?

Answer (score 12):

There are at least three well-known mechanisms.

## External Counters

When the first shared pointer to an object is created, a separate reference count object is created and initialized to 1. When the pointer is copied, the reference count is increased; when a pointer is destroyed it is decreased. Pointer assignment increases one count and decreases another (in that order, or else self-assignment `ptr=ptr` will break). If the reference count hits zero, no more pointers exist and the object is deleted.

## Internal counters

An internal counter requires that the object pointed to has a counter field. This is usually achieved by deriving from a specific base class. In exchange, this saves a heap allocation of the reference count, and it allows repeated creation of shared pointers from raw pointers (with external counters, you'd end up with two counts for one object)

## Circular links

Instead of using a counter, you can keep all shared pointers to an object in a circular graph. The first pointer created points to itself. When you copy a pointer, you insert the copy in the circle. When you delete it, you remove it from the circle. But when the destroyed pointer pointed to itself, i.e. when it's the only pointer, you delete the pointed-to object.

The downside is that removing a node from a circular single-linked list is rather expensive as you have to iterate over all nodes to find the predecessor. This can be especially painful due to poor locality of reference.

## Variations

The 2nd and 3rd idea can be combined: the base class can be part of that circular graph, instead of containing a count. Of course, this means that the object can be deleted only when it points to itself (cycle length 1, no remaining pointers to it). Again, the advantage is that you can create smart pointers from weak pointers, but the poor performance of deleting a pointer from the chain remains an issue.

The exact graph structure for idea 3 doesn't matter too much. You could also create a binary tree structure, with the pointed-to object at the root. Again, the hard operation is removing a shared pointer node from that graph. The benefit is that if you have many pointers on many threads, growing part of the graph is not a highly contended operation.

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr` uses `External Counters` approach. Is there a way to implement weak_ptr with `Internal Counters` approach (without rewriting the earth)?

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, but it's rather complex. You'll need a custom `operator new` and especially its matching `operator delete` in the base class. You use this to create a "tombstone" where the base class used to be, so that the `weak_ptr` continues to point to that tombstone.

Comment: @MSalters That sounds like it would require at least the use of `std::launder` (scary). Also it assumes that there's a common base class in the first place - which isn't always the case with intrusive ref counting.

Answer (score 0):

They hold an internal reference count that is incremented in the shared_ptr copy constructor/assignment operator and decremented in the destructor.  When the count reaches zero, the held pointer is deleted.

Here's the Boost library [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) for smart pointers.  I think the TR1 implementation is mostly the same as `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

"Shared pointer is a smart pointer (a C++ object wih overloaded operator*()  and operator->()) that keeps a pointer to an object and a pointer to a shared reference count. Every time a copy of the smart pointer is made using the copy constructor, the reference count is incremented. When a shared pointer is destroyed, the reference count for its object is decremented. Shared pointers constructed from raw pointers initially have a reference count of 1. When the reference count reaches 0, the pointed object is destroyed, and the memory it occupies is freed. You do not need to explicitly destroy objects: it will be done automatically when the last pointer's destructor runs. "
From [here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Boost_shared_pointers).