# avoid copying during array conversion between numpy and mxnet

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, copy, mxnet

I want to reduce a memory copy step during my data processing pipeline.

I want to do the following:

1. Generate some data from a custom C library
2. Feed the  generated data into a MXNet model running on GPU.

For now, my pipeline does the following:

1. Create a C-contiguous numpy array via `np.empty(...)`.
2. Get the pointer to numpy array via `np.ndarray.__array_interface__`
3. Call the C library from python (via ctypes) to fill the numpy array.
4. Convert the numpy array into mxnet `NDArray`, this will **copy** the underlying memory buffer.
5. Pack `NDArray`s into a `mx.io.DataBatch` instance, then feed into model.

Please note, before being fed into model, all arrays stay in CPU memory.

I noticed a `mx.io.DataBatch` can only take a list of `mx.ndarray.NDArray`s as `data` and `label` parameter, but **not** numpy arrays. [It works until you feed it into a model.](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/4382) On the other hand, I have a C library that can write directly to a C-contiguous array.

**I would like to avoid the *memory copying* in step 3.** One possible way is somehow getting a raw pointer to buffer of `NDArray`, while totally ignoring numpy. But whatever works.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a hacky way to achieve this. Here's a small example.

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
import mxnet as mx

m = mx.ndarray.zeros((4,4))
m.wait_to_read() # make sure the data is allocated

c_uint64_p = POINTER(c_uint64)

handle= cast(m.handle, c_uint64_p) # NDArray*
ptr_  = cast(handle[0], c_uint64_p) # shared_ptr<Chunk>
dptr = cast(ptr_[0], POINTER(c_float)) # shandle.dptr

n = np.ctypeslib.as_array(dptr, shape=(4,4)) # m and n will share buffer
```

I derived the above code by looking at MxNet C++ source code. Some explanation:

First, note the `NDArray.handle` attribute. It's a `c_void_p`. Read the python source code, you will know it's `NDArrayHandle`. Now dive into `src/c_api/c_api_ndarray.cc` code, it's reinterpreted as `NDArray*`.

In the source tree, go to `include/mxnet/ndarray.h` and find `NDArray` class. The first field is:

```
/*! \brief internal data of NDArray */
std::shared_ptr<Chunk> ptr_{nullptr};
```

Checking `Chunk`, which is a struct defined inside `NDArray`, we see:

```
  /*! \brief the real data chunk that backs NDArray */
  // shandle is used to store the actual values in the NDArray
  // aux_handles store the aux data(such as indices) if it's needed by non-default storage.
  struct Chunk {
    /*! \brief storage handle from storage engine.
               for non-default storage, shandle stores the data(value) array.
     */
    Storage::Handle shandle;
```

Finally, `shandle` is defined in `include/mxnet/storage.h`:

```
  struct Handle {
    /*!
     * \brief Pointer to the data.
     */
    void* dptr{nullptr};
```

Writing a small program shows `sizeof(shared_ptr<some_type>)` is 16. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200664/how-is-the-stdtr1shared-ptr-implemented) question, we can guess `shared_ptr` is composed of two pointers. It's not too hard to figure out the first pointer is the pointer to data. Putting everything together, all that needed are two pointer de-referencing.

---

On the down site, this method cannot be used in production environment or large projects. It could break in future release, or introduce tough bugs and security holes.