# Why std::shared_ptr control block need to hold a pointer to managed object with its correct type

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, raii, tr1

I am looking at the shared_ptr implementation in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201435/4208109). One question that is not entirely clear to me is, why in addition to the pointer stored with `T*` type in shared_ptr class itself, author also needs to store the second copy of the managed object's pointer with its concrete type in the control block (i.e. `U* p;` in `auximpl`). I understand why we need this for custom deleter, but not for actual pointer. It looks like this complies with the requirements of the standard, when I read control block description in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) page. Author made the following comment about this

> "this is needed to properly manage all the cases of T being a base for
> whatever U having multiple T in the derivation hierarchy"

but I still can't come up with an example of when this will really be required. Can someone please demonstrate it with an example?

Thank you,
-Grigor

Comment: Just at an example: `class A{public: virtual ~A(){}}; class BA: public A{}; class CA: public A{}; class D: public BA, public CA{}; std::shared_ptr<A> p(new D);`. Not knowing about `D*` the inner `delete p.ptr` will not work as expected.

Comment: Doesn't that give `error: 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'`?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/PavfvcaoY Lots of other errors that I believe are all due to D being ambiguous. But once you dynamic_cast to `BA` or `CA` it works. And then the virtual destructor A::~A() will do the right thing. So how is the inner pointer needed? I would agree with the Op that the inner pointer is for custom deleters.

Comment: If I understand 273K example correctly he needed to derive from A virtually in BA and CA. This will fix the compilation errors, however I still don't get why would we want to store the second instance of pointer in the control block. We could just hold it as T* in shared_ptr itself (not in the control block) and pass it to destroy function as a parameter to call custom deleter on it. Thus the auximpl struct should have the following prototype in my opinion (see below comment)

Comment: template <typename T>
class shared_ptr 
{
…
 template<class Deleter>
    struct auximpl: public aux
    {
        Deleter d;

        auximpl(Deleter x) : d(x) {}
       void destroy(T* ptr) override { d(p); } 
    };
…
}

Comment: The managed object pointer may not be in the shared_ptr. It has to have a pointer to something and a pointer to the control block. Destruction needs the pointer to the managed object though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One case is when using `shared_ptr`'s alias capability.

Create a `shared_ptr` using an object's member but the control block is the same and thus the reference count.

```
class holder : public std::enable_shared_from_this<holder>
{
 int member;

public:
 
 std::shared_ptr<int> get_member() { 
  return std::shared_ptr<int>(shared_from_this(), &member);
 }
};

std::shared_ptr<int> foo()
{
 auto ptr = std::make_shared<holder>();
 return ptr->get_member();
}
```

the object created in the `make_shared` call won't be freed until the object returned from foo's reference count goes to 0.