# Can a unique_ptr<>() initialization fail?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, exception-safe

From the documentation of [std::unique_ptr<>()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), what may happen when initializing the pointer is not clear to me.

When allocating an `std::shared_ptr<>()`, it allocates a memory buffer to handle the reference counter. So I may get an `std::bad_alloc` exception.

Could something similar happen when initializing a unique pointer?

I am asking the question because if it does, I may actually lose what I was attempting to have delete through the unique pointer. For example:

```
void deleter(FILE * f)
{
  fclose(f);
}

void func()
{
  ...
  FILE * f(fopen("/tmp/random", O_CREAT | ...));
  if(f == nullptr) ...handle error...
  std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&deleter)> raii_file(f, deleter);
  ...
}
```

So, if the initialization of `unique_ptr<>()` can throw, I may end up keeping the file `f` open forever. (I use `FILE *` as an example, any similar resource could be affected.)

Opposed to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585569#35585810), I obviously cannot use `std::make_unique<>()` since I'm not just allocating memory.

Would it be safer to initialize the `std::unique_ptr<>()` before the `fopen()`, and then save the value in there after?

```
  ...
  std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&deleter)> raii_file(nullptr, deleter);
  FILE * f(fopen("/tmp/random", O_CREAT | ...));
  if(f == nullptr) ...handle error...
  raii_file = f;
  ...
```

Or would that have similar problems?

Comment: `std_::unique_ptr` ctor is `noexcept`, as per the docs you linked.

Comment: @BadZen, I guess I have to learn to read the documentation properly. I was expecting to see that in the declaration at the top.

Comment: Yeah, the formatting is a little rough... =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of `unique_ptr`'s constructors are `noexcept`. So no, there's no way that it can fail. If your `Deleter` type throws on copy/move, then the `noexcept` will catch it and call `std::terminate`.